# Electron react sending data two-way in ipcMain and ipcRenderer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I am trying to create a communication between `ipcMain` and `ipcRenderer` in electron. I am using [electron react boilerplate](https://electron-react-boilerplate.js.org/)

So first step was adding this part to main:

```
app
  .whenReady()
  .then(() => {
    ipcMain.handle('dialog:openFile', () => {
      console.log('test');
    });
```

second step was to add it in `preload` file:

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI', {
  openFile: () => ipcRenderer.invoke('dialog:openFile'),
});
```

and the third step is where I get stuck. I am trying to add it in react component by:

```
await window.electronAPI.openFile();
```

But I get `Property 'electronAPI' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.` error. What is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Webby are you sure that the **preload** file is loaded in the browserWindow Object? Also that is necessary that you have the property contextIsolation on **True**

something like this

```
const win = new BrowserWindow(
{
  fullscreen: false,
  webPreferences: {
    contextIsolation: true,
    preload: path.join(__dirname, '../path/to/your/preload.js'),
  },
},
```

Comment: hey, I didn't have to set up `contextIsolation ` to true, I just looked at https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate main.ts file and followed it and it worked

Comment: @Webby you may answer your own question, e.g., what did you change in your react component, here and help others.